# Order by custom values Yii2

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, yii2

i want to sort record on custom field, but it give me error in yii2, can any one help me.

`->orderBy(player.PlayerRole, 'G','D','M','F');` 
  where G, D, M and F are custom values. this work fine in mysql but in   **yii2**   it does not.

i have also tried this one

```
$expression = new Expression('field(player.PlayerRole,G,D,M,F)');
```

`->orderBy($expression)`

here is the full query

```
$expression = new Expression('field(player.PlayerRole,G,D,M,F)');
return (new Query())
->select('*')
->from('tablename')`enter code here`
->orderBy(player.PlayerRole, 'G','D','M','F');
->all();
```

Comment: Can you provide most of your code and the way object defined?

Comment: Please have a look a the complete query given in the post above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this issue:

> Please read the doc carefully. orderBy takes an array, and an array element can be an Expression. So you should use $query->orderBy(array($expression)) instead of $query->orderBy($expression).

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/553

so try `->orderBy(array($expression))`